# How to Join a table to a group_contact in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
select concat('[',group_concat(inn.str),']') into string4  from (
        select concat(
            '{"idmm":',customer.id,
            ',"cd":"',customer.code,
            '","nm":"',customer.name,

            '"," Order":"', 

            '","des":"', customer.description,                   
            '"}' )as a_string
        from
            customertable customer

    )
```

How do I join the Order table to have the order_name joined to the string?
In the middle of the above string you see `'"," Order":"'`, right? I want to join the `Order` table to pull the `order_name` as the customertable has `order_id` and concatenate to the string.

The customertable has columns

```
id int(10)  
order_id int(10)  
code char(6) 
name varchar(45) 
description varchar(500)
```

and Ordertable has columns

```
order_id int(10) 
order_name varchar(500)
```

Comment: What is inn.str?

Comment: Can you edit your question, order your code and put your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM Customers c
JOIN Orders o USING(order_id)
```